# Visual studio IIS express doesn't take changes to html file

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have the simplest web project, with one signalR hub and one html file that has a demonstration interface.

At some point, no matter what I do, the html file changes are not present when I debug.

It works fine when I publish, but the html file is stuck in some past state during debug.

I tried:

- Rebuild, clean,
- Reopen VS, reboot the computer,
- Delete build folder and obj folder,
- Hard refresh on browser, disable cache when dev tools are open, also
- **Another browser**,
- Ancient Mayan ritual for debugging code,
- Every option under browser link in VS,
- Playing around with VS build options (Tools, Options, Projects and Solutions, Build and run) and finally messing with the html file properties (copy always, copy if new).

All to no avail. I am using visual studio 2015 Enterprise.

The code itself is here if of any use, but I have no idea how to reproduce:
[Git Hub repo](https://github.com/rcabrantes/GroupCommunication.)

Pretty sure it's not relevant but the state I'm stuck in similar if not exactly the one at faf3ba8 on the repository.